# Passing variable into an SQL/MYSQL statement in c/c++

Tags: c++, c

I would like know how exactly the syntax is when passing a variable into an SQL statement in c/c++? I've search through various sites but still I can't get the exact way of doing so. PLease advice, anyone.

Comment: Neither C nor C++ have any concept of SQL statements. Please indicate in your question what library you're using, and ideally, an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't indicated in your question what library you're using to generate SQL statements, but typically they use strings, in which case simple concatenation should work. Taking [mysql_query()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-query.html) as an example:

```
#include <string>

std::string tableName = "Foo";

// Assume we already have a valid `connection`:

mysql_query(connection, ("SELECT * FROM " + tableName).c_str());
```

Comment: and in case you don't already know, you DO need a library to do that